# Excel increment serial number based on string match

Tags: excel

[image: Auto increment based on string match]

How can I generate the next CST number automatically to be 1238 and 204 for VAT. 
I tried INDEX&MATCH, MAX, COUNTIF all throwing circular reference error.

CST & VAT is entered manually in random order.

Hope there is a formula. Unfortunately I don't know VBA. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In B4 formula will be:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A3=A4;$B$2:$B3;0))+1
```

this is array formula and when you confirm this formula you must press ctrl+shift+Enter

Comment: Placed the formula in B4 and confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Then I dragged it down till B20 to check how it works. Sequential number is generating perfectly. But the point where CST/VAT entry(say A7) stops it's showing stray entries in B7 onwards as 1 2 3 and so on till B20. However upon entering CST/VAT in A8 it updates B8 to correct sequence number and the 1 2 3 gets pushed down. Guess I can live with that. Thanks for the formula though :)

Comment: @rhlchd  It would work if nested in: if(A4<>"",formula here,"") Much better and short answer.

Comment: hmm, you're correct. Works that way in avoiding those stray values. Thanks again @NiteshHalai

Answer (score 1):

Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> the following array formula in B8 and drag it down:

```
=IF(A8<>"",IF(A8="CST",INDEX($B$2:B7,MAX(IF($A$2:A7="CST",ROW($A$2:A7)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:A7,1,1))+1)),0)+1,INDEX($B$2:B7,MAX(IF($A$2:A7="VAT",ROW($A$2:A7)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:A7,1,1))+1)),0)+1),"")
```

EDIT: The above fomula has a flaw in that if you include anything other than CST or VAT in column A, it will return last VAT value + 1. Use the following to avoid this:

```
=IF(A12="CST",INDEX(B6:B11,MAX(IF(A6:A11="CST",ROW(A6:A11)-ROW(INDEX(A6:A11,1,1))+1)),0)+1,IF(A12="VAT",INDEX(B6:B11,MAX(IF(A6:A11="VAT",ROW(A6:A11)-ROW(INDEX(A6:A11,1,1))+1)),0)+1,""))
```

Comment: You have started with **A8<>""**, why not directly start with **IF(A8="CST"** ? Is it a way to avoid circular reference?

Comment: If I had started it with **IF(A8="CST"** then if you drag that to a cell where column A is not yet filled, it will return the last VAT value + 1. Also note that if you include anything other than CST or VAT in column A, it will increase the last VAT value by 1.  The logic of the formula would be is value in col A is "CST", then look for last CST and add 1, else look for last VAT and add 1.

Comment: @rhlchd Please check the edited answer for a better formula.